# (R) Finding proportion of population defectives at probability 0.1 acceptance

Tags: r, statistical-sampling

I'm using the following R code:

```
library(AcceptanceSampling)

x <- OC2c(50, 2, type="hypergeom", N=4000)
plot(x, xlim=c(0,0.2))
```

which generates the plot:

[image]

I will like to find the proportion when `P(accept)` (Y-axis) is 0.1. Is there a way to do this in R? I have a feeling this package does not allow direct computation of that according to its documentation at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/AcceptanceSampling/AcceptanceSampling.pdf.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't get this exactly, but you can get close. `x` is an S4 object, and the slots you're interested in here are `paccept` and `pd`. We can get the `pd` value with the `paccept` value *closest* to 0.1 of all the `paccept` values:

```
idx <- which.min(abs(x@paccept - 0.1))
round(cbind(paccept = x@paccept[idx], pd = x@pd[idx]), 3)
#      paccept  pd
# [1,]    0.11 0.1
```

Comment: That's fast! Thanks for the insights, I'll take note them. I'm also trying to solve via obtaining the root to the operating characteristic equation, but then again the libraries that are able to give a solution only give approximate ones..